# datetime difference with date with 0 seconds

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the hours between two dates in python, the first one is an input date, the second one is a date from the name of a miniseed file.

```
  dt = datetime.strptime("2019-04-15T00:37:00", '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
  //dt is the input date
  for filename in os.listdir('.'):
        if filename.endswith(".mseed"): 
            file_struct = filename.split('.')
            datetime_object = datetime.strptime(file_struct[0], '%Y%m%d%H%M%S') 
            hours = abs((dt- datetime_object).seconds)//3600
  
            print(dt, datetime_object, hours)
            continue
        else:
            continue
```

the result is:

> (datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 15, 0, 37, 10), '20190405082044', 16)
>
> (datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 15, 0, 37, 10), '20190405000000', 0)
>
> (datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 15, 0, 37, 10), '20190405083710', 16)

looks like there is something wring with 20190405000000 (his datetime obj is `datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 5, 0, 0)` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For total elapsed seconds use `total_seconds` instead of `seconds`

```
hours = abs((dt -datetime_object).total_seconds()) // 3600
```

Notice that `total_seconds` is a method  and hence the brackets